# Assign unique index to similar rows in R based on Levenshtein distance

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to assign a index to identify similar rows in R. The sample data is below

```
test_data <- data.frame(char_name = c("star Lord", "Star Lords", "Star Lords", "Star Lord", 
                                      rep("Gamora", 2), rep("GamOOOra", 2)),
                        address = rep(c("Space", "Universe"), 4),
                        phone = c(rep(123, 4), rep(456, 4)))
```

And the desired output:

```
output_data <- data.frame(char_name = c("star Lord", "Star Lords", "Star Lords", "Star Lord", 
                                      rep("Gamora", 2), rep("GamOOOra", 2)),
                        address = (c(rep(c("Space", "Universe"), 4))),
                        phone = c(rep(123, 4), rep(456, 4)), 
                        same_person_ind = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4)))
```

The logic for the `same_person_ind` is:

1. Group items with similar `char_name` together based on Levenshtein distance less than or equal to 3
2. For each group of similar `char_name`, if the Levenshtein distance of either `address` OR `phone` is less than or equal to 3 then assigned a unique identifier to the group.

I have looked into both the `stringdist` and `dplyr` packages but I don't know how to implement my logic in R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: You might also look at the RecordLinkage package.  Something like this function could give your char_name elements a common variable; then do the same for phone and same_person and create same_person_ind as TRUE when two out of three are < 3.  # compareJW <- function(string, vec, cutoff) {
   require(RecordLinkage)
   jarowinkler(string, vec) > cutoff
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a helper function that groups the elements of a vector according the a certain distance. I am using `adist`  here:

```
### col.     : vector of words to search by distance
### max_dist : maximum distance between similar words
create_groups <- 
  function(col.,max_dist=3) { 
    nn <- as.character(col.)
    grp_names_id <- 
      as.data.frame(t(unique((adist(nn)<max_dist))))

   .to_data_frame <- 
      function(x)
        data.frame(char_name=nn[grp_names_id[,x]],grp=x)
    res <- 
      unique(do.call(rbind,
                     lapply(seq_len(ncol(grp_names_id)),
                            .to_data_frame)))

    res
  }
```

For example, applying this to `char_name` we get 3 groups:

```
res <- create_groups(test_data$char_name)
##    char_name grp
## 1  star Lord   1
## 2 Star Lords   1
## 4  Star Lord   1
## 5     Gamora   2
## 7   GamOOOra   3
```

Applying this to your data and merge the result :

```
res <- create_groups(test_data$char_name)
res <- merge(test_data,res
##    char_name  address phone grp
## 1   GamOOOra    Space   456   3
## 2   GamOOOra Universe   456   3
## 3     Gamora    Space   456   2
## 4     Gamora Universe   456   2
## 5  star Lord    Space   123   1
## 6  Star Lord Universe   123   1
## 7 Star Lords Universe   123   1
## 8 Star Lords    Space   123   1
```

Now the idea is to apply the same process by subgroup already formed in the previous step. It is natural here to use `data.table` to apply operations by group. For example:

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(res),grp,char_name)

res[,c("key","grp1"):= {
  create_groups(address)

},"grp,char_name"]

##     char_name  address phone grp      key grp1
## 1:  star Lord    Space   123   1    Space    1
## 2:  Star Lord Universe   123   1    Space    1
## 3: Star Lords Universe   123   1    Space    1
## 4: Star Lords    Space   123   1 Universe    2
## 5:     Gamora    Space   456   2    Space    1
## 6:     Gamora Universe   456   2 Universe    2
## 7:   GamOOOra    Space   456   3    Space    1
## 8:   GamOOOra Universe   456   3 Universe    2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does address my biggest problem which is how to assigned the grouping. I think after running the code over `phone` and `address`, I'll concatenate the groups' results and then assign the final index accordingly.